# Manufacturer name using mac address

Tags: java, mac-address

If you know any free web service or site that has manufacturer name of mac addresses
I have a task to find device's manufacturer name using mac address. Its is a functionality I have to implement in java

Comment: http://www.macvendorlookup.com/api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for something like this: http://www.coffer.com/mac_find/. You would have to send a query, then analyze the result HTML, and look up TD elements with `table2` class.