# How to see what manufacturer owns a MAC address range/prefix

Tags: api-design, mac-address, nmap, ieee

I am looking for a way to programmatically get the name of the vendor that owns a MAC address within a block/range that they purchased. Preferably by querying some API or database, language agnostic. Or if there is some other way that applications do it that I am unaware of.

For example, running `nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24` with root privileges yields

```
...
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.111
Host is up (0.35s latency).
MAC Address: B8:27:EB:96:E0:0E (Raspberry Pi Foundation)
...
```

... and that tells me that the Raspberry Pi Foundation "owns" that MAC Address, within the prefix range that they own: B8:27:EB.
However, I am not sure how `nmap` knows this, nor how I could find this out myself. Parsing nmap output is not an ideal solution for me. Here's what I found from digging online:

- [This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18013005/manufacturer-name-using-mac-address) references a [site that appears to do this](http://www.coffer.com/mac_find/), however it appears to not have been updated since 2013, nor does it expose any API endpoints. Most notably, it does not have the newer block of MAC Addresses that the Raspberry Pi Foundation reserved for their newer models (under Raspberry Pi Team, or something along those lines).
- I found that the IEEE handles these registrations through [their site](https://regauth.standards.ieee.org/standards-ra-web/pub/view.html#registries), however it appears to be for their customers and I could not find an exposed endpoint for their search function.
- On that same IEEE page linked above, it looks like I can get a CSV file of their entire database. However that seems large, and would have to be actively kept up-to-date. Does nmap come with an updated database generated from those files locally?

If a public-facing API like I'm envisioning doesn't exist, I'll make one myself for fun. I'd first like to know if I'm thinking about this wrong and if there is an official, "canonical" way that I have not found. Any help would be appreciated, and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maintainers of nmap keep a list of prefixes as part of the tool. You can see it here:
https://github.com/nmap/nmap/blob/master/nmap-mac-prefixes

They keep this up to date by periodically importing the public registry on this site:
https://regauth.standards.ieee.org/standards-ra-web/pub/view.html#registries

Note that those files are rate-limited so you should *not* be querying those csv files ad hoc as part of a software package; rather you should do what nmap does and keep an internal list that you synchronize periodically.

I'm not aware of a publicly available tool to query them as an API; however, creating one that works the same way that nmap does would be fairly trivial. nmap does not update that file more than once or twice a year which makes me suspect that the list doesn't significantly change often enough that keeping your own list would be too onerous (you could even download nmap's list every so often).